# date picker in angular 2

Tags: angular, datepicker

i am using ng2-datepicker in my poc. which event will be fired on model change? i tried (change),(onModelChange),(selectedChanged) but these are not working.

in html i use

```
<ng2-datepicker [options]="options" [(ngModel)]="date" [disabled]="fourthdrpdwn"></ng2-datepicker>
```

in ts file

```
// public  store_service_data:any=[];
// for adding datepicker support file start here 
date: DateModel;
options: DatePickerOptions;

// for adding datepicker support file end here 
constructor(private configservice:ConfigService) {}

ngOnInit(){
  this.configservice.get_service_data();
  this.options = new DatePickerOptions();
  this.firstdrpdwn=true;
  this.seconddrpdwn=true;
  this.thirddrpdwn=true;
  this.fourthdrpdwn=true;
}
```

Comment: Try (ngModelChange) wich is the default event when you are working with [ngModel]

Comment: correct answer thnks buddy .